# iPhone Tab Bar design related question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am in the process of designing an app that will begin on an account page.  The account page is split in to two views.  The first view prompts the user for an email and password and saves this to a plist once enterred.  To expedite the login process I also prompt the user for a pin.  If a plist exists with account info, a pin view is loaded instead of the email/password view so the user can login only with their pin.  Once the login is complete I would like the user to interact with a tab bar at the bottom of the view at all times.  The tab bar will allow the user to navigate through three other parts of the app or return to the login screen.  What is the best way to implement this.  Specifically, I am wondering should I set up a standard UITabBarController with four UIViewControllers linked to tabs?  Should the first view controller default to the email/password view and switch out to the pin view only upon the condition of a login with an existing plist in storage?  Is this optimum or does someone have a better suggestion?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm thinking you shouldn't be saving their username and password in a plist file.

Comment: Keychain should be a good place to store the username & password.

Comment: I am encrypting the information with the pin.  But I will look into the keychain option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have login tab option available to the user all the time, then what you are thinking would work. But then after logging in would you disable the login tab? Or would you add a logout option there?

Otherwise if you do not want the login tab to be present all the itme, I would suggest starting the app with a regular UIViewController and displaying the email/password or pin interface on it based on plist data. Once login is successful, you could replace the root view controller with the UITabBarController containing only the three tabs that you actually want.

Comment: I would like for the a login option to be available at all times.  I will be hiding the tab bar during login.  Thanks for the confirmation.